# A-FRAME 1.0.4 How can I define animation mouseenter and mouseleave properly

Tags: javascript, animation, aframe, mouseenter, mouseleave

I have an entity contain an image using as a button
I want to scale that button larger from "1 1 1" to "2 2 1" when mouse hover.
I use JS to generate that button. Other attributes are set and working, but the animation doesn't work. Could you please show me what is wrong?

```
_buttonA.setAttribute("animation__mouseEnter", "property: scale; type: scale; from: 1 1 1; to: 2 2 1; startEvents: mouseenter; dur: 500");

 _buttonA.setAttribute("animation__mouseLeave", "property: scale; type: scale; from: 2 2 1; to: 1 1 1; startEvents: mouseleave; dur: 500");
```

Comment: Without code to run and look at it will be hard to help you. Glitch is a great option: https://glitch.com/~aframe

Comment: @DiegoMarcos  that code is working if I hard added it to html. But when I generate it by setAttribute of JS. The value is not set properly, check it in inspector, their values are empty: animation__mouseenter="" animation__mouseleave=""

Answer (score 0):

After generating that object via JS, I see the value of the animation attribute is empty. I don't know why the setAttribute isn't working properly here.

I try to use: createAttribute and setAttribtueNode as below and it works:

```
        var animation__mouseEnter = document.createAttribute("animation__mouseEnter");
        var animation__mouseLeave = document.createAttribute("animation__mouseLeave");
        animation__mouseEnter.value ="property: scale; type: scale; from: 1 1 1; to: 1.3 1.3 1; startEvents: mouseenter; dur: 200";
        animation__mouseLeave.value ="property: scale; type: scale; from: 1.3 1.3 1; to: 1 1 1; startEvents: mouseleave; dur: 200";
        buttonA.setAttributeNode(animation__mouseEnter);
        buttonA.setAttributeNode(animation__mouseLeave);
```

P/S: I can use below setAttribute to set animation for other object:
`_im.setAttribute("animation__rotation", "property: rotation; loop: true; from: 0 0 0; to: 0 360 0; dur : 5000");` 
and in inspector of chrome browser, it also shows empty, but it works
[image of the object in inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iDZsu.png)

if using createAttribute and setAttributeNode, the value of animation is displaying fully in the inspector [like this snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j5Ace.png)